# How to override "inherited" z-indexes?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, z-index

I am needing to override the notion of inherited z-indexes.

For instance in this code

```
<style>
div{
  background-color:white;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
</style>
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 2;">
   div 1
   <div style="position: fixed; z-index: 3;">
     div 2
   </div>
 </div>
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 2;">
 div 3
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/epoqo3/3

I want for `div 2` to be displayed, but instead `div 3` is displayed. How can I change this behavior without changing my structure.

Comment: I've tried this in Chrome, IE7 and Firefox 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't give a child higher `z-index` than its parent. You may want to rethink your design if this is the case, or consider popping the child out of the parent temporarily to show it on a higher index than its parent.

The physical order of the divs in this case can help as well. If you move the first down after the last, you'll get the preferred rendering. But this may not be ideal for your situation.

Comment: Well, my problem is that this works with a `<ul><li>` type system as a menu system with jquery, so it's pretty difficult to just change it.

Comment: You would likely have to work up some javascript to remove the child temporarily, show it, and then restore it to its original position. That, or you can clone the inner child, hid the original, show the clone, and then delete the clone when finished, re-displaying the original.

Comment: As noted in my updated-answer, the only other way would be to physically re-order the divs, putting the first after the last, causing it to be painted last (and thus appear on top).