# Fix arrow(img) prev and next

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
   header
</div>
<div>
   sidebar
</div>
<div>
   content

   <a href="#"><img src="prev.png"></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="next.png"></a>

</div>
```

how do I fix the arrow in the center of the div content to the right and left?

http://jsfiddle.net/shvj40ta/embedded/result/

[image]

---

**SOLUTION**

The question below helped me understand about override:

[How to override "inherited" z-indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458303/how-to-override-inherited-z-indexes/2458315#2458315)

I put the z-index in div arrows, not in children divs

With the help of user @justinas I got the solution

http://jsfiddle.net/gislef/3by7r0ek/1/

Comment: please share a site link here....

Comment: Thank you, I can not share that is not yet published

Comment: Your divs dont even have a size. You need to work on this before of asking for help.

Comment: @DhavalPatel please see: jsfiddle.net/shvj40ta/embedded/result

Comment: :( my account was blocked to questions, I really struggled to make clear questions and learn how to program better with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With css 'position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -(height / 2)';

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
.left,
.right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  /* actual height is 40 */
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.left {
  border-right-color: black;
  left: 5px;
}
.right {
  border-left-color: black;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Justinas, it code is functional but arrow are not within the content div , the left arrow appears in the sidebar div

Comment: @Gislef Does your content wrapper has `position: relative` applied? If not, absolute positioned elements will take it's position from closest non-static positioned element (so `relative` or `absolute` parent, by default it's `html`)

Comment: please see: http://jsfiddle.net/shvj40ta/embedded/result/ I want the arrows are only within the contents of the div

Comment: @Gislef Arrows must be `absolute`, to `fixed`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gislef/shvj40ta/1/embedded/result/ I'm trying to get fixed inside the div content, the left arrow this correctly positioned but the right arrow does not

Comment: but that arrow is above the content, in my example it floating arrows are on the screen and hinders not read the contents, but inside the div content, the only problem is the right arrow

Comment: Thank you @justinas with your help I finally got. http://jsfiddle.net/gislef/3by7r0ek/1/